# How to dynamically add new component to the current component without using ViewContainerRef?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I know that i can insert a dynamic component using ViewContainerRef to a particular position in current comopnent ([Dynamic Component Loader - Angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)). But i want add a new component which will always be in top of my current component. Can i do that without using ViewContainerRef?

Comment: Is it possible to use ngIf to control whether the new component is shown?